# What is the correct way to copy an object from an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios

so I want to copy an object from an `NSMutableArray`:

```
self.myObject = [self.myMutableArray objectAtIndex:self.currentIndex];
```

But when `currentIndex` changes, `myObject` changes to the object corresponding to the new index.

What is the best way to approach this?

**Edit:**

Here's more or less what I'm trying to achieve:

```
self.currentIndex = 0;

self.myObject = [self.myMutableArray objectAtIndex:self.currentIndex];

self.currentIndex = 1;

//After here I want myObject to remain the same, but it doesn't
```

Comment: There is not enough info to answer this properly: if you do not know the index of the object, you need to know something else about it that lets you identify your object uniquely. Please tell us what makes the object that you need to fetch from the array different from objects at other indexes.

Comment: your question is unclear...so you want your object to change or not?

Comment: Sorry I just updated it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Invoke the `copy` method on the object from the array, and then take care of releasing it yourself:

```
self.myObject = [[self.myMutableArray objectAtIndex:5] copy];
...
[self.myObject release];
```